# How to use regular expressions?

Tags: php

i want to split some caracters into a string . The string contains this `define("coco","coco");` i want with regular expressions split the 'define' , the '(' , the ')' and replace the ',' by '=' . How can i do?

Comment: What do you mean by split? Because, you split strings into arrays, and the sum (join) of characters is a string.

Comment: by split I say the removal of the string

Comment: Best guide ever for me: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks , i already goes on it , i'm small confused

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to delete ("split") those values this is quite simple, you don't need Regex.

```
<?php

$str = 'define("coco","coco")';

echo str_replace('define(', '', str_replace(",", "=", str_replace(")", "", $str)));
```

Another way is by using preg_replace, but we have already an answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with :

```
$string = 'define("coco","coco")';

$newString = preg_replace('/define\(("[^"]+"),("[^"]+")\)\;/isU', "$1=$2", $string);
```